# Android Push Notification - Irremovable Push Notification Untill Condition Has Been Fulfilled

Tags: java, android, android-activity, push-notification

I would like to make a local push notification in Android which cannot be removed by simply swiping right. A condition in the app should be fulfilled beforehand. Is this possible and if so, how do i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do that .

> Use FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT

```
 Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
        notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
```

OR

> Use FLAG_NO_CLEAR

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_NO_CLEAR